# JAXB fails to recognize type inheritance

Tags: java, xml, inheritance, jaxb

I have a JAXB generated class, with a collection with the abstract type COBJECT.

COBJECT has multiple descendants, and these descendants also have abstract descendants too. 
A snippet from the class hierarchy is as follows:

```
COBJECT (abstract)
|
|---CDEFINEDOBJECT
    |
    |--CDOMAINTYPE (abstract)
       |
       |---CCODEPHRASE
```

When I add an object of CCODEPHRASE to a collection with type COBJECT , such as

```
protected List<COBJECT> children;
```

JAXB attempts to create COBJECT, which is an abstract type, and it fails. I've tried to add

```
@XmlElementRefs({
        @XmlElementRef(type = ARCHETYPEINTERNALREF.class),
        @XmlElementRef(type = CONSTRAINTREF.class),
        @XmlElementRef(type = CDEFINEDOBJECT.class),
        @XmlElementRef(type = ARCHETYPESLOT.class),
        @XmlElementRef(type = CCODEPHRASE.class)        
    })
protected List<COBJECT> children;
```

before children field, but I got "Type or any of its subclasses are not known " exception in response.

The XML input contains XSI:TYPE= ... attribute. How do I make JAXB handle this inheritance structure?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to ensure that the `JAXBContext` is aware of the parent class and all the subtypes.  This can be done by passing then all in when the JAXBContext is created.

```
JAXBContext.createContext.newInstance(Parent.class, Child1.class, Child2.class);
```

Or you can leverate an `@XmlSeeAlso` annotation.  This lets you specify all the child classes so that you only need to inlcude the root when creating the JAXBContext:

```
@XmlSeeAlso({Child1.class, Child2.class}) {
public class Parent {
}
```

**For More Information on JAXB and Inheritance**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-xsitype.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-substitution.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/ignoring-inheritance-with-xmltransient.html

Comment: Thanks, it was my extreme stupidity that caused the problem actually :) Apparently I've forgotten to update generated java class files in the client project. There goes a few hours for nothing...